# Route after filters are not being canceled when before filter fails

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-routing

According to the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters), when the before filter of a route fails, the after filter is canceled, but it doesn't seem to be the case. I'm have a navigation pulled from the database. My route before filter whether on a Route::group or a plain route checks whether a person has visited that a certain page. If it hasn't, it will return a Redirect::route('new route').

The route after filter will add a row to a visited_pages table.

What is happening when I click on a link where I haven't visited its prerequisite page, is it will redirect. But - it will still add a row to the database. So the after isn't being canceled. It still fires.

The way I tested this was I was logged in and was on a page. Cleared the page visits from the database. I then clicked on my "classroom" nav item. This requires "orientation"

What gets entered into the database is a page visit in the following in this order:

1. Classroom
2. Classroom Instructions
3. Orientation

What I'm expecting to see is:

1. Orientation

**Routes**

```
Route::group(array("prefix"=>"classroom","before"=>"checkPrerequisite"),function()
{
    Route::get('/',array(
        'as'=>'classroom',
        'uses'=>'ClassroomController@index',
        'after'=>'addvisit',
        ));
    //there are more routes here, but they don't need after filters.
    Route::get('/instructions',array(
        'as'=>'classroom.instructions',
        'after'=>'addvisit',
        function()
        {
            return View::make('classroom.instructions');
        }
    ));
});
```

**Before filter**

```
    Route::filter('checkPrerequisite', function($route, $request)
{
    $sPrerequisite = Navigation::where('url','=',Navigation::where('url','=',Route::currentRouteName())->first()->prerequisite)->first();
    // get the module id from session
    $mod_id = Session::get('current_module');
    // get the page from the user_page_visits
    $page = Auth::user()
                    ->pages()
                    ->where('module_id','=',$mod_id)
                    ->where('nav_id','=',$sPrerequisite->id)
                    ->first();

    if(!$page) return Redirect::route($sPrerequisite->url);
});
```

**After filter**

```
Route::filter('addvisit', function($route, $request, $response)
{
    // get the current route
    $current = Route::currentRouteName();
    // get the id of the navigation item with this route
    $nav_id = Navigation::where('url','=',$current)->first()->id;
    // get the module id from cache
    $mod_id = Session::get('current_module');
    // see if the page has been visited
    $page = Auth::user()
                    ->pages()
                    ->where('module_id','=',$mod_id)
                    ->where('nav_id','=',$nav_id)
                    ->first();

    if($page)
    {
        // if it has been visited, increment the visits column by 1
        $page->increment('visits');
    }
    else
    {
        // otherwise, create a new page visit
        $visit = new UserPageVisits;
        $visit->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $visit->module_id = $mod_id;
        $visit->nav_id = $nav_id;
        $visit->save();
    }
});
```

Comment: You don't even have the `addvisit` filter in the route you posted. I assume that's just the case with the code on SO?

Comment: Correct - it's just the case with the code on SO. I have updated it. Sorry :)

Comment: Related: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/652